# How to open windows terminal settings.json as Vs code?

Tags: windows, terminal

I'm Korean I have an issue toady
recently I have tried to make a development atmosphere on windows. (because I just used Anaconda. I want to make totally new env)
so I set up Ubuntu 18.04 and many things following a youtube.

when the YouTuber press [Crtl + , ] in windows terminal, it opens as VS code
but my shoes, it opens as text file!!! (below picture)

what's wrong with me??

[image: t]

How can I fix it?
Plz give your intelligent idea

Comment: You haven't explained, what problem needs to be fixed. Opening a text document in a text editor doesn't read like a problem.

Answer (score 1):

make `.json` file anywhere (like Desktop) and right click that file, click `open with` (in Korean `연결 프로그램`), unless you can't find Visual Studio Code, choose `choose another app` (in Korean `다른 앱 선택`).

Click Visual Studio Code in the following window.